# ethereum wallet:Your computer's clock is not synced.

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

i am using geth

```
VRSION:
   1.8.20-stable-24d727b6
```

and ethereum wallet `Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-9-3` and i am using `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` and on wallet startup wallet is showing the error message
here is the error message

```
To successfully synchronize with the Ethereum network, you need to sync your computer's clock with a time sync server. To enable a time sync server, install "ntp" via "apt-get install ntp".
```

i did run `apt-get install ntp` but the problem persists wallet is showing above error message after running this command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also configure `ntp` in order to have it set the clock.

Here's a [great tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/ntp-server-configuration-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) on how to do it on Ubuntu 18.04.